# Multi Step Registration in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm trying to build multi-step registration form.

I have a route `/register`

**Step 1**
I'm posting this form to step2

```
route('register', ['step' => 1])
```

[image]

**Step 2**

And i'm getting data of step1 and put inside hidden inputs. And posting to third step for ending registration. If it is successful no problem. But what happened if registration fails ?

```
route('register', ['step' => 2])
```

**Step 3**

```
route('register', ['step' => 3])
```

If Registration fails i'm redirecting user to step2.

Here is my redirect code.

```
    $new_user = $request->all();
    $validator = Validator::make($new_user, $this->rules());

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($new_user)
            ->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag()->toArray());
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
```

If validation fails i'm redirecting to step2 everything ok. But i'm seeing forms in picture (Step 1) But my uri is /register?step=2

What is the problem. Where am i making mistake ?

**UPDATE: (Route Definitions)**

```
Route::get('/register', [
    'uses'       => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister',
    'as'         => 'register',
    'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

Route::post('/register', [
    'uses'       => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister',
    'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);
```

**UPDATE 2: (getRegister and postRegister)**

Note: I didn't finished coding getRegister and postRegister.

**getRegister**

```
public function getRegister(Request $request)
    {
        if(!$request->has('step'))
        {
            /**
             * Eğer kayıt ekranında ?step=1,2 vs. yoksa direk ?step=1 e yönlendirme yapıyoruz.
             */
            return redirect()->route('register', ['step' => 1]);
        }

        $countries = (new LocationCountry)->getAllCountries()->toArray();
        foreach($countries as $key => $country)
        {
            $countryNames[$key] = $countries[$key]['translation'] = trans('country.'.$country['code']);
        }

        array_multisort($countryNames, SORT_STRING, $countries);

        /**
         * Ülke ve Zaman Dilimi için Varsayılan Seçimi
         */

        $default = new \stdClass();

        $default->country = (Lang::locale() == 'tr') ? 'TR' : 'US';

        $default->timezone = (Lang::locale() == 'tr') ? 'Europe/Istanbul' : 'America/New_York';

        $timezones = (new DateController)->getTimeZoneList();

        return view('auth.register.index', compact(['timezones', 'countries', 'default']))
            ->with('orderProcess', TRUE);
    }
```

**postRegister**

```
public function postRegister(Request $request){
        if(!$request->has('step'))
        {
            /**
             * Eğer kayıt ekranında ?step=1,2 vs. yoksa direk ?step=1 e yönlendirme yapıyoruz.
             */
            return redirect()->route('register', ['step' => 1]);
        }

        if ($request->get('step') == 2)
        {
            $new_user = $request->all();

            $new_user['tc_citizen'] = (!isset($new_user['tc_citizen'])) ? 0 : 1;
            $new_user['area_code']  = (new LocationCountry)->getCountryAreaCodeByCode($new_user['country']);

            $cities = (new Location)->getCities();

            /**
             * Eğer Post Durumunda ise ve town değişkeni varsa...
             */
            if($request->has('town'))
            {
                $towns = (new Location)->getTowns($request->get('city'));

                if(!$towns->isEmpty())
                {

                }
            }

            return view('auth.register.step2', compact(['new_user', 'cities']))
                ->with('orderProcess', TRUE);
        }

        if($request->get('step') == 3)
        {
            /**
             * Kayıt Sonuç Sayfası
             */
            $new_user = $request->all();
            $validator = Validator::make($new_user, $this->rules());

            if ($validator->fails())
            {
                return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($new_user)
                    ->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag()->toArray());
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the route definition?

Comment: i added route definitions

Comment: Could you please also post the `getRegister` method, so I can see how you're handling steps for that action.

Comment: i added postRegister and getRegister

Comment: @CihanKüsmez did you see my answer below? Did it help in any way?

Answer (score 6):

It's because your redirection is telling the browser to do a GET request on the `register?step=2` URL. And in your `getRegister` method you don't check for the `step` value (hence you see the same form as for GET `step=1`).

---

I see two possible solutions:

- either you tweak your redirection so that it does a POST request to `step=2` (might be tricky)
- or you serve a different page for GET request to `step=2`

I would advise you for the second option:

- The form in `step=1` should do a POST to `step=1`, which should redirect to a GET `step=2` if everything is fine (using flash cookie to pass the variables)
- The form in `step=2` should do a POST to `step=2`, which should redirect to a GET `step=3` if everything is fine (using flash cookie to pass the variables)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
return redirect()->back()
     ->withInput(array_merge($new_user, ['step', $step-1]))
     ->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag()->toArray());
```

I hope it works fine for you.